# How do I get the text written in UITextView/UITextField automatically saved?

Tags: objective-c

I have created about 10-20 UITextViews, but everytime I write something in the simulator, it disappears when exiting the viewcontroller, going back to the "menu" and then clicking back to the viewcontroller with the UITextViews. I really need the text to be saved, but I can't figure out how to do it, despite looking on Youtube etc.

Comment: *despite looking on Youtube [sic]*... how is "looking on Youtube" going to help you? You mean for a tutorial on how to do this? It sounds like you might need the [`NSUserDefaults` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a more functional grounding in Objective-C (I sense that you're "biting off more than you can chew" here). (As a side note, it's improper Stack Overflow etiquitte to sign your posts with something like "Thanks" as it creates unnecessary "noise" in your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have separate save and load method for each uitextview or you can store them in json file. Input : Textfield.text, Section : which textfield do you want to save and load. Then you just call the load method in the ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void) saveTemporary:(NSString *)input :(NSString *)section
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:input forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"textfield_%@",section]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(NSString *)loadTemporary :(NSString *)section
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadingString = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"textfield_%@",section]];
    return  loadingString;
}
```

Here is for the json Tutorial : 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5